# Camel case lost when pasting in Visual Studio

Tags: html, data-binding, knockout.js, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 (to be exact: version 12.0.3) my data-bindings are being reformatted **when I paste from the clipboard**.

I have this simple data binding:

```
<div  data-bind=" 'Text':camelCaseProperty}></div>
```

When I **cut and then paste** the `camelCaseProperty` bit in my code is reformatted. The code looks like this after pasting:

```
<div data-bind=" 'Text' camelcaseproperty}></div>
```

Notice that `camelcaseproperty` is **no longer camel case**! In addition, the colon was removed.

Has anyone experienced this? Does anyone know how to prevent it?

Comment: Just to be sure, have you confirmed this is Resharper's doing? You can (at least in V7 you could) suspend Resharper in the options with a button click.

Comment: just checked, it still does it with resharper suspended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be due to Visual Studio's Auto Formatting options as you have an extra/unopened `}` at the end:

[image]

In addition you have HTML (Web Forms) options:

[image]

Comment: Fixed by changing client attributes to "As Entered". The issue also occurred when I had very long attributes over multiple lines. this fixed both cases, Thanks!